# How to retrieve optional parameters from SMSC header (i.e SAR_MSG_REF_NUM, SAR_SEGMENT_SEQNUM,SAR_TOTAL_SEGMENTS) we are using JSMPP jar

Tags: java

How to retrieve optional parameters from SMSC header (i.e SAR_MSG_REF_NUM, SAR_SEGMENT_SEQNUM,SAR_TOTAL_SEGMENTS) we are using JSMPP jar

```
if(deliverSm.getOptionalParameter(Sar_msg_ref_num.class)!=null && deliverSm.getOptionalParameter(Tag.SAR_SEGMENT_SEQNUM)!=null && deliverSm.getOptionalParameter(Tag.SAR_TOTAL_SEGMENTS)!=null){
        log.info("Optional Parameter SAR_MSG_REF_NUM || SAR_SEGMENT_SEQNUM || SAR_TOTAL_SEGMENTS is present");
        try {
            OptionalParameter messageRefNum=deliverSm.getOptionalParameter(Tag.SAR_MSG_REF_NUM);
            OptionalParameter segmentSeqNum=deliverSm.getOptionalParameter(Tag.SAR_SEGMENT_SEQNUM);
            OptionalParameter totalSegmentsNum=deliverSm.getOptionalParameter(Tag.SAR_TOTAL_SEGMENTS);

            log.info("MsgRefNum"+(( org.jsmpp.bean.OptionalParameter.Short)messageRefNum).getValue());
            log.info("SegmentSeqNum"+(( org.jsmpp.bean.OptionalParameter.Short)segmentSeqNum).getValue());
            log.info("TotalSegments"+(( org.jsmpp.bean.OptionalParameter.Short)totalSegmentsNum).getValue());

            short MessageRefNum=((org.jsmpp.bean.OptionalParameter.Short)messageRefNum).getValue();
            short SegmentSeqNum=((org.jsmpp.bean.OptionalParameter.Short)messageRefNum).getValue();
            short TotalSegments=((org.jsmpp.bean.OptionalParameter.Short)messageRefNum).getValue();
            deliverSm.getSequenceNumber();
            deliverSm.getSmDefaultMsgId();


        smsMessage.setMessageRefNum(MessageRefNum);
        smsMessage.setSegmentSeqNum(SegmentSeqNum);
        smsMessage.setTotalSegments(TotalSegments);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        log.info("Exception Occured please check "+e);
    }
```

We are getting the below exception as below for the above implementation.

```
06-12-18 16:09:55.170[DEBUG][pool-2-thread-2][com.mobily.sms.listener.smpp.impl.SMPPListenerImp]- deliverSm.getShortMessage(): [B@49cf9f
06-12-18 16:09:55.170[ERROR][pool-2-thread-2][org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession$ResponseHandlerImpl]- Invalid runtime exception thrown when processing DeliverSm
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jsmpp.bean.OptionalParameters.get(OptionalParameters.java:238)
        at com.mobily.sms.listener.smpp.impl.SMPPListenerImp.onAcceptDeliverSm(SMPPListenerImp.java:78)
        at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.fireAcceptDeliverSm(SMPPSession.java:587)
        at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.access$1(SMPPSession.java:585)
        at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession$ResponseHandlerImpl.processDeliverSm(SMPPSession.java:614)
        at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX.processDeliverSm0(SMPPSessionBoundRX.java:104)
        at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX.processDeliverSm(SMPPSessionBoundRX.java:52)
        at org.jsmpp.session.PDUProcessTask.run(PDUProcessTask.java:90)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
06-12-18 16:09:55.171[ERROR][pool-2-thread-2][org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX]- Failed processing deliver_sm
org.jsmpp.extra.ProcessRequestException: Invalid runtime exception thrown when processing DeliverSm
        at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession$ResponseHandlerImpl.processDeliverSm(SMPPSession.java:620)
        at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX.processDeliverSm0(SMPPSessionBoundRX.java:104)
        at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX.processDeliverSm(SMPPSessionBoundRX.java:52)
        at org.jsmpp.session.PDUProcessTask.run(PDUProcessTask.java:90)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```